# Download a file to the desktop where field name equals file name in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, file-get-contents, helper, file-exists

I have code written to allow someone to enter a date. if the submit date equals the file name then codeigniter should download the file to the desktop. The code shown makes sense to me but when I run it I get 'file was not found'. I can pull the file up on the server though and the name matches what is returned in the mysql database. My end goal is to be able to download the file with the same filename as my submission_date field

```
if($this->input->post('submit')) {
        $trlr_num = $this->input->post('trlr_num');
    } elseif($this->uri->segment(4)) {
        $trlr_num = $this->uri->segment(4);
    }

    if( !empty($trlr_num)) {
        $query = $this->trailer_model->select_trailer_draw($trlr_num);
        $result =& $query->row_array();

        if( !empty($result)) {
            // Get filepath to bill
            $directory = 'http://intranet.gmwdc.com/inc/img/inspection/upload';
            $file = $directory.'/'.$result['submission_date'];

            $this->load->helper('download');


            if(file_exists($file)) {
                $data = file_get_contents($file);
                force_download($result['submission_date'],$data);
            } else {
                $this->session->set_status_data('error','File was not found.');
            }

            return;
        } else {
            $this->session->set_userdata('error','No Inspection Draw Found');
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be referring wrong directory or file name. Also, it seems that `$file` is having no extension.

```
 $file = $directory . '/' . $result['submission_date'] . $extension;
```

**Edited**

Instead of `$directory` try Codeigniter `FCPATH` which points to your Codeigniter installation directory.

```
$file = FCPATH . 'dir1/dir2/' . $result['submission_date'];
```

Comment: I was using CONCAT in my SQL query to add the .png extension. I tried your suggestion with the $extension. I removed the CONCAT in my sql query and added $extension = '.png';   This did not go through. Thanks for the help.

Comment: hmm if extension is fine. check ```$directory```. what it contains?

Comment: Weird, I get that it's an undefined variable when I add it as $data['directory'] = $directory; to pass it to my view

Comment: Thank you for the fix Madan!  $file = FCPATH . 'inc/img/inspection/upload/' . $result['submission_date'];  this worked for me.